# exercise of vectorial function of real variable

Tags: calculus

How can I solve the following exercise?

Define a function $f:\left [ 0,4 \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ whose rank is a square contained in the  plane $x+y+z=1$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The square has same cardinality as $[0,4]$.

Comment: By "rank", do you mean the set of points $\{f(x): x\in [0,4]\}$? If so, the correct English is "range".